# Can redis be configured to save only to disk and not in memory?

Tags: redis, scaling

I am facing some scaling issues with my redis instances and was wondering if there's a way to configure redis to save data only to disk (and not hold it in memory). That way I could just increase disk space and not RAM.

Right now my instances are getting stuck and just hang when they reach the memory limit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Redis, atm, is an in-memory database. That means that all data that it manages resides first and foremost in RAM.